# How to get back Kafka producer and consumer configuration (Java API)?

Tags: java, api, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

The use case is following. 
I am passing producer or consumer reference over many objects instances in Java code. 
At some of them I would like to do some checks for the Kafka configuration.
It means I would like to get back, what effective configuration  is stored in Kafka Producer/Consumer (including defaults).
I do not see anthing explicit in java docs:

- [KafkaProducer](https://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html)
- [KafkaConsumer](https://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html)

So, how to get **back** Kafka producer and consumer configuration?

Comment: what did you end up doing? I am performing something similar.

Comment: There are options to log complete Kafka configuration. Log4j2 config:

    <Logger name="org.apache.kafka" level="INFO" additivity="false">
      <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
    </Logger>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible. I have to admit it could be a useful feature for showing the "core" configuration properties at least (avoiding the possibility to get the "secrets" for authentication stuff for example).
The only solution that I see today for you is to have a link between the consumer/producer instance and the related properties bag used for setting the client configuration. I understand it's a waste of memory because such configuration is internally in the client but you need to keep your properties bag for having it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem with **my** config is that ist is mine :-), and could be detached from Producer/Consumer. 
If I have application server, where there are many beans, and they are using the same producer/consumer. There are questions:
When producer was created, what configuration it has, was it created only one time, or there were overlapping "new KafkaProducer/Consumer"s. Of course in perfect software all is clear and done well. But sometimes I have bugs :-) and debbuging current config is hard, easier would be just to log config or prepare some validation functionality.

Comment: I have the same question @SewerynHabdank-Wojewódzki what did you end up doing? Currently I have a map keeping track of what config belongs to what producer.

Comment: There are options to log complete Kafka configuration. Log4j2 config:

    <Logger name="org.apache.kafka" level="INFO" additivity="false">
      <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
    </Logger>